# In Android, can I find the number of parts in an MMS message after only receiving the 1st part?

Tags: android, mms, contentobserver

I have an MMS content observer set up in my app, which gets troggered whwnever a new MMS message arrives. It then queries ""content://mms/inbox" and retrieves any unread messages. The problem is that the MMS arrives in parts (text, and any audio/pic/video attachments come in separately) Or at least the content observer gets triggered multiple times (whenever each MMS part is downloaded). So, when the first part comes in, my app detects it, but there really isn't anything there except for the subject. A few seconds later, the next part comes in, and my app adds it to the first one. So, if there are 3 or more parts, this becomes a nuisance, since the user never knows if there are going to be more parts coming.

So, I'd like to wait until all the parts come in before notifying the user that there is a new MMS and showing it to them. However, I don't see anything in the content provider that states home many parts in total will be coming through. So is there something I'm missing, or any other way to determine how many parts will be there in total? (without just having a while loop on an a random interval checking if another part came in)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is check for the `_id` of the last item in the `content://mms/inbox` uri inside onChange.

You need to store the previous _id and compare it to the _id of the last item (`cursor.moveToLast()`)of the cursor after you query for `content://mms/inbox`. If the `_id` is the same, you can choose to ignore/discard the previous message and instead store this one.

You can save last message's id and compare it to the id of the message that is returned by `cur` in `onChange`. you then can simply disregard the message if ids are the same.

```
// might contain mistakes, but you'll get the idea:
protected void querySMS() {
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(u, null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToNext(); 
    if (lastId == cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex("_id")))
        return;
    lastId = cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
    ... //continue as it was
}
```

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with my question -- I want to know how many parts are there by just getting the first part (before the rest came in)

Comment: As far as I know, that will not be possible.

Comment: Ok. I though that there is some field somewhere that says how many parts will follow